# Linguagem C - A estrutura pula diretamente para ELSE ignorando os parametros de IF

Tags: c, if, else

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    //Escolhe entre nome do personagem e classe

    int p,c;
    printf("RPG teste\n");

    printf("Digite um nome para o seu(a) personagem:");
    scanf("%s",&p);
    printf("Escolha uma classe, digitando entre Guerreiro ou Monge:");
    scanf("%s",&c);

    if (c=="Guerreiro"){
        printf("Guerreiro");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Monge");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Você esta tentando comparar uma cadeia de caracteres com um número, por isso sempre vai entrar no else

Comment: Por favor **não vandalize as perguntas**. Não tem razão alguma pra excluir a pergunta, até porque a mesma foi bem aceita e tem respostas também bem aceitas. A pergunta não pertence ao usuário, pertence a comunidade, se você tem motivo particular para remover o vinculo do seu perfil com a pergunta, entre em contato diretamente com a SE e relate teu caso para que seja analisado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem que revisar um pouco os conceitos em C, tem alguns "errinhos" no seu código, como:

- As variáveis `p` e `c` são declaradas como `int`, mas no código são utilizadas para guardar uma palavra.

Quando você utiliza `int`, você está especificando que a variável irá receber um número inteiro, ou seja, não poderá guardar outros tipos de dados, não podendo guardar uma palavra, por exemplo.
Para isso você pode especificar uma variável do tipos `char` (string), que vai guardar um número total de caracteres, por exemplo:

```
char variavel[50];
```

- Na estrutura do `if`, você tenta comparar `c` diretamente com a palavra "Guerreiro".

Mesmo que você definisse o tipo da variável para `char`(string), como no exemplo acima e tentasse fazer um `if` de comparação direta, daria "erro", ele nunca irá entrar na condição do `if`, pois não é possível comparar diretamente uma variável do tipo `char`(string). Salvo exceção, onde `char` é utilizada para guardar um único caractere, por exemplo:

```
#correto
char variavel;
variavel = 'a';
if(variavel == 'a');

#incorreto
char variavel[20];
variavel = "palavra";
if(variavel == "palavra");
```

Quando se utiliza somente `char variavel`, você pode guardar um único caractere, permitindo fazer uma comparação em um `if` normal com aspas simples `'a'`, mas quando se utiliza `char variavel[20]`, você está declarando uma string que pode guardar uma quantidade de caracteres nela, dependendo do valor que você especificar na atribuição.

Nesse caso a comparação é diferente, existe uma função na biblioteca `<string.h>` que faz essa comparação, essa função é a `strcmp()`, que você pode ver uma explicação melhor [nessa página](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Basicamente, ela retorna um número dependendo da situação da comparação, podendo verificar se é maior, igual ou menor:

```
c = "variavel";
if(strcmp(c, "variavel") == 0); #a função retorna 0, pois são iguais
```

Assim, você consegue fazer uma comparação entre duas palavras.

- Utilizar `scanf()` para ler palavras.

Apesar de funcionar, não é o mais adequado utilizar o `scanf()` para ler palavras, pois ele não irá conseguir ler um nome composto, por exemplo:

```
scanf("%s", variavel); #foi digitado o nome José Maria
printf("%s", variavel); #imprime somente o nome José
```

Então, o mais adequado nessa situação, é utilizar o `gets()`, que vai guardar tudo o que for digitado, você pode ler mais sobre ele [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm).

Por fim, mas não menos importante, está o código completo, de como deveria ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    char p[20];
    char c[20];
    printf("RPG TESTE\n");
    printf("Digite um nome para o seu(a) personagem:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(p);
    printf("\nEscolha uma classe, digitando entre Guerreiro ou Monge:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(c);
    if(strcmp(c, "Guerreiro") == 0){
        printf("\n\nGuerreiro");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\nMonge");
    }
}
```

Comment: O código compilou perfeitamente, obrigado pela explicação

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Danilo! Seja bem-vindo!

A solução para seu problema envolve alguns conceitos importantes de programação estruturada C.

Uma variável é um espaço na memória. Ela possui nome, endereço e pode armazenar um valor.

Quando se declara uma variável, deve-se especificar o tipo de variável que se deseja.

- `int`: valores inteiros (-2, 0, 1)
- `float`: valores flutuantes (-3.5, 1.0, 5.33)
- `double`: valores flutuantes grandes (3.1415926535897932384626433832795)
- `char`: caracteres ('a', 'b', 'c')
- `bool`: valores booleanos (true, false)

Quando se deseja armazenar uma palavra (sequência de caracteres, *string*), deve-se usar um vetor. Vetor é uma sequência de espaços na memória. Cada espaço é chamado de índice, que inicia a partir do 0 (zero). O índice zero é o endereço padrão do vetor.

```
char nome[4];
nome[0] = 'A';
nome[1] = 'N';
nome[2] = 'A';
nome[3] = '\0';
```

O valor `'\0'` é usado para indicar o final da *string*, por isso é necessário reservar um espaço a mais no vetor.

Existem outras formas de se inicializar uma *string*.

```
char nome[] = "ANA";
char nome[4] = "ANA";
char nome[4] = {'A','N','A'};
char nome[10] = "ANA";
```

Caracteres solitários são atribuídos entre aspas simples `''`, enquanto que *strings* são atribuídas entre aspas duplas `""`.

A biblioteca `stdio.h` possui funções de leitura (entrada pelo teclado) `scanf(arg_1, arg_2)` e escrita (saída pela tela) `printf(arg_1, arg_3)`.

Cada função possui dois argumantos, mas há 3 tipos de argumentos, neste caso.

- arg_1: formatação do valor
- arg_2: endereço do espaço na memória
- arg_3: nome do espaço na memória

Para se ler ou escrever um valor, deve-se especificar o formato desse valor.

- %d: inteiros e booleanos (1 - true, 0 - false)
- %f: flutuantes
- %fl: flutuantes grandes
- %c: caracter
- %s: *string*

Note que variáveis booleanas retornam 1 ou 0, por isso compartilham do mesmo especificador de formato que os inteiros. Para os flutuantes, em especial, é possível especificar o número de casas antes e depois do ponto, por exemplo: %2.3f para números 0.333, 25.587, 4.444.

```
int num = 0;
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("numero: %d\n", num);

char nome[10];
scanf("%s", nome);
printf("nome: %s", nome);
```

Observe que para ler do teclado um valor inteiro, o endereço informado foi `&num` ("e" comercial seguido pelo nome da variável). Já para ler uma *string*, o endereço informado foi `nome` (apenas o nome do vetor). Isso é feito pois o endereço do vetor é vinculado ao nome do próprio vetor, apontando para o índice zero do vetor.

Agora vamos para a solução do problema em questão.

Para comparar se duas *strings* são iguais, é necessário usar a função de operação de *string* `strcmp(string_1, string_2)` presentes na biblioteca `string.h`.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(){

        //Escolhe entre nome do personagem e classe

        char p[20];
        char c[20];
        printf("RPG teste\n");

        printf("Digite um nome para o seu(a) personagem:");
        scanf("%s",p);
        printf("Escolha uma classe, digitando entre Guerreiro ou Monge:");
        scanf("%s",c);

        if (strcmp(c,"Guerreiro") == 0){
            printf("Guerreiro");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Monge");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Bonus: Outra função da biblioteca string.h que pode ser útil é `strcpy(Nome, "nome de alguém")`.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, estudarei os pontos indicados. O código compilou perfeitamente

Comment: De nada, rapaz! :)